# How to prevent the rounding off when getting doubleValue from string?

Tags: iphone, ios5, gps, xcode4.2, core-location

I am getting latitude and longitude from server in JSON which is in string format then i am using this latitude and longitude by converting the values of latitude and longitude in double value by using default doubleValue function but by using this value is rounded off. So, How can i prevent the rounding off when getting doubleValue from string?
Here is my code

```
  CLLocationCoordinate2D defaultLoc;

            defaultLoc.latitude = [[self.obj valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
            defaultLoc.longitude = [[self.obj valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]; 

            NSLog(@"latitude : %f longitude : %f",defaultLoc.latitude,defaultLoc.longitude);
```

Comment: What does the string normally look like, and what does the output of the double value truely look like?  Are you SURE it is truly rounding and if so how?  I see it being converted from your string to double using doubleValue, but then you are simply converting it back to essentially a string using %f in your print statements!

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier `%f` rounds the double values to six decimals by default. Try specifing the format as `%.10f`or whatever number of decimals you need.

Comment: I had a similar problem to the original question and this answer was the correct solution for me, too. This should probably be marked as the accepted answer, @iosuser.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem i had.
I solved it by , having the lat long data from JSON as NSString.
Create an object class to hold the NSString equivalent of your lat and long

```
 NSString * lattodeletetest;
 NSString * longtodeletetest;
 lattodeletetest=[dict objectForKey:@"Lat"];
 longtodeletetest=[dict objectForKey:@"Lon"];
 NSArray *array2=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:lattodeletetest,longtodeletetest, nil];
 NSString * coordinateString2=[array2 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
 safe.strLatLong=coordinateString2;

NSLog(@"%@",safe.strLatLong); //prints 12.758493847753464,71.488293492438438
```

By this way it is possible to preserve the lat and long obtained from JSON without edits.

To use it as CLLOcationCoordinate2d ,
use

```
 NSString *str=strLatLong;
 NSArray *array=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
 lattodeletetest=[array objectAtIndex:0];
 longtodeletetest=[array objectAtIndex:1];
 CLLocationCoordinate2D location=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lattodeletetest doubleValue],[longtodeletetest doubleValue]);
```